# Discrepancy between summary() and anova() of linear mixed model

Tags: r

I have fitted a linear mixed model with split-plot design to assess the effects of water, nitrogen and phosphorus on BWC (biomass-weighted 2c-value, achieved by summing the product of each species' 2C-value(DNA content) with its biomass fraction (species subplot biomass/total subplot biomass)：

`model1.1<-lmer(log(BWC)~W*N*P+(1|year)+(1|W:Block),data=BWC)`

There are two levels for W(0,1), N(0,1) and p(0,1) I would like to use boxplot to report my results with the output of the linear mixed model. However, I'm confused with the output of the linear mixed model.

1. The estimated value (slope) for W*N*P in model1.1 is negative, Does that mean WNP treatment will decrease BWC comparing to control plot? But we can see the BWC was highest in boxplot under the WNP treatment.
2. There is a discrepancy between summary() and anova(), for example,  the significance for N and P effects. Estimate value for N is-4.0911 which means N addition decreased BWC But N effect was insignificant. How can I report the treatment effects like N?

Many thanks for any comments.
Boxplot of WNP treatment on BWC:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrzBI.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKOFt.png
(Sorry for the links,it seem I need at least 10 reputations to post images)

The summary() and anova() output:

```
> summary(model1) 

Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: BWC ~ W * N * P + (1 | year) + (1 | W:Block)
   Data: BWC
REML criterion at convergence: 2969.1
Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.93847 -0.71228 -0.07573  0.68191  2.92589 
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 W:Block  (Intercept)  0.9169  0.9575  
 year     (Intercept)  0.8346  0.9136  
 Residual             18.2966  4.2774  
Number of obs: 515, groups:  W:Block, 14; year, 10

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  10.8498     0.6985  46.5200  15.532  < 2e-16 ***
W1            2.0844     0.8969  45.9613   2.324  0.02460 *  
N1           -4.0911     0.7364 486.0288  -5.556 4.56e-08 ***
P1           -2.0460     0.7600 490.1120  -2.692  0.00734 ** 
W1:N1         4.6738     1.0394 485.9800   4.497 8.65e-06 ***
W1:P1         0.9695     1.0687 485.9809   0.907  0.36478    
N1:P1         5.7550     1.0687 485.9773   5.385 1.13e-07 ***
W1:N1:P1     -3.3306     1.5100 485.9541  -2.206  0.02788 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
         (Intr) W1     N1     P1     W1:N1  W1:P1  N1:P1 
W1       -0.645                                          
N1       -0.531  0.414                                   
P1       -0.515  0.401  0.488                            
W1:N1     0.376 -0.582 -0.708 -0.346                     
W1:P1     0.366 -0.566 -0.347 -0.706  0.488              
N1:P1     0.366 -0.285 -0.689 -0.706  0.488  0.502       
W1:N1:P1 -0.259  0.400  0.488  0.499 -0.688 -0.708 -0.708

> anova(model1)
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
      Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
W     750.15  750.15     1  11.90 40.9995 3.519e-05 ***
N      10.84   10.84     1 485.95  0.5926   0.44177    
P      29.14   29.14     1 494.92  1.5926   0.20755    
W:N   290.51  290.51     1 485.95 15.8778 7.793e-05 ***
W:P    15.54   15.54     1 485.96  0.8493   0.35721    
N:P   536.85  536.85     1 485.95 29.3415 9.562e-08 ***
W:N:P  89.01   89.01     1 485.95  4.8648   0.02788 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

```
> emmeans::emmeans(model1,pairwise~N*P*W)
$emmeans
 N P W emmean    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 0 0 0  10.85 0.699 46.9     9.44    12.26
 1 0 0   6.76 0.696 46.2     5.36     8.16
 0 1 0   8.80 0.721 52.1     7.36    10.25
 1 1 0  10.47 0.721 52.1     9.02    11.91
 0 0 1  12.93 0.696 46.2    11.53    14.33
 1 0 1  13.52 0.696 46.2    12.12    14.92
 0 1 1  11.86 0.721 52.1    10.41    13.30
 1 1 1  14.86 0.721 52.1    13.42    16.31

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Comment: When `W`, `N` and `P` are all 1, you would add all the relevant coefficients to get the effect, not just look at the `W1:N1:P1` coefficient. If you do that, you'll get 14.86, as in your `emmeans` result.

Comment: Thanks, Gregor. I will try to figure it out.